# Reading UTF-8 .properties files in Java 1.5?

Tags: java, file, utf-8, properties

I have a project where everything is in UTF-8. I was using the Properties.load(Reader) method to read properties files in this encoding. But now, I need to make the project compatible with Java 1.5, and the mentioned method doesn't exist in Java 1.5. There is only a load method that takes an InputStream as a parameter, which is assumed to be in ISO-8859-1.

Is there any simple way to make my project 1.5-compatible without having to change all the .properties files to ISO-8859-1? I don't really want to have a mix of encodings in my project (encodings are already a time sink one at a time, let alone when you mix them) or change all my project to ISO-8859-1.

With "a simple way" I mean "without creating a custom Properties class from scratch".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One strategy that might work for this situation is as follows:

1. Read the bytes of the `Reader` into a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html).
2. <strike>Once that is completed, call [`toByteArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toByteArray%28%29)</strike>  See below.
3. With the `byte[]` construct a [`ByteArrayInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html)
4. Use the `ByteArrayInputStream` in [`Properties.load(InputStream)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29)

---

As pointed out, the above failed to actually convert the character set from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1.  To fix that, a tweak.

After the BAOS has been filled, instead of calling `toByteArray()`..

1. Call [`toString("ISO-8859-1")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toString%28java.lang.String%29) to get an ISO-8859-1 encoded `String`.  Then look to..
2. Call [`String.getBytes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29) to get the `byte[]`

Comment: There are two problem I can see with this approach is you are still passing in the same bytes that was read which is UTF-8. The second problem is that there is an assumption the properties file is small because it is being loaded up into memory.

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano *"there is an assumption the properties file is small because it is being loaded up into memory"*  If you had a properties file large enough to blow away (the better part of) 64 Meg. of standard JRE memory, you should really be looking at something like a DB to store the info.  ;)

Comment: Agreed, though personally I wish a BDB like data store is part of the JRE at times like this.  Or at least something like a File based HashMap that would just cache 128MB of name value pairs so we can pass the management of name-value pair reference data as a properties file to the Business Analysts.

Comment: Also, never underestimate what inexperienced programmers can do.  I have a Checkstyle warning flag whenever it detects "ByteArrayOutputStream" in the code to ensure that we really need it.

Comment: Actually in my case the properties files are quite small, so this does the trick. I agree that more general answers will be useful for Googlers though.

Answer (score 3):

Could you use [xml-properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#loadFromXML%28java.io.InputStream%29) instead? As I understand by the spec .properties files should be in `ISO-8859-1`, if you want other characters, they should be quoted, using the `native2ascii` tool.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is open a thread that would read data using a BufferedReader then write out the data to a PipedOutputStream which is then linked by a PipedInputStream that load uses.

```
PipedOutputStream pos = new PipedOutputStream();
PipedInputStream pis = new PipedInputStream(pos);
ReaderRunnable reader = new ReaderRunnable(pos, new File("utfproperty.properties"));
Thread t = new Thread(reader);
t.start();
properties.load(pis);
t.join();
```

The BufferedReader will read the data one character at a time and if it detects it to be a character data not to be within the US-ASCII (i.e. low 7-bit) range then it writes "\u" + the character code into the PipedOutputStream.

ReaderRunnable would be a class that looks like:

```
public class ReaderRunnable implements Runnable {
  public ReaderRunnable(OutputStream os, File f) {
    this.os = os;
    this.f = f;
  }
  private final OutputStream os;
  private final File f;
  public void run() {
    // open file
    // read file, escape any non US-ASCII characters
  }
}
```

Now after writing all that I was thinking that someone should've had this problem before and solved it, and the best place to look for these things is in Apache Commons.  Fortunately, they have an implementation there.

https://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/ReaderInputStream.html

The implementation from Apache is not without flaws though.  Your input file even if it is UTF-8 must only contain the characters from the ISO-8859-1 character set.  The design I had provided above can handle that situation.

Answer (score 1):

What I personally do in my projects is I keep my properties in UTF-8 files with an extension .uproperties and I convert them to ISO at the build time to .properties files using `native2ascii.exe`. This allows me to maintain my properties in UTF-8 and the Ant script does everything else for me.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your build engine you can \uXXXX-escape the properties into the build target directory. Maven can filter them via the **native2ascii-maven-plugin**.

Answer (score -1):

What I just now experienced is, Make all .java files also UTF-8 encoding type (not only properties file where you store UTF-8 characters). This way there no need to use for InputStreamReader also. Also, make sure to compile to UTF-8 encoding.

This has worked for me without any added parameter of UTF-8.

To test this, write a simple stub program in eclipse and change the format of that java file by going to properties of that file and Resource section, to set the UTF-8 encoding format.